# how to select all the data received in the fetch request and check for each item

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, fetch

i get login and password data as object [
{
"id": "1",
"login": "admin",
"password": "admin"
},
{
"id": "2",
"login": "abc",
"password": "nmp",
},
{
"id": "3",
"login": "hjjk",
"password": "sddr",
}
]
now I only check the first object

```
async function authWithLoginAndPassword() {
    const response = await fetch('');
    const data = await response.json();
    const logUser = data[0].login;
    const passwordUser = data[0].password;
    return { logUser, passwordUser }
}
submit.addEventListener('click', async ()=> {
    try {
        ...
        let register = await authWithLoginAndPassword();
        if(loginUser !== register.logUser) {
           ...
        } 
        if(loginUser === register.logUser) {
           ...
        }
        if(password !== register.passwordUser) {
            ...
        } 
        if(password === register.passwordUser) {
            ...
        }
        if(loginUser === register.logUser && password === register.passwordUser) {
            ...
        }
     } ...
})
```

how can I check in another function for the all username and password? and how can i write the if statement with the mistake, for example if logins goesn't match, the div appears with an error that the login is incorrect and border turns red. and similarly with the password, but another div appears there. If to use filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
data.forEach(row => {
  console.log(row); // do the matching here
})
```

or filter array like this

```
const loggedUser = data.filter(value => { return value.login === loginUser && password === value.password})[0];
```

You can update authWithLoginAndPassword

```
async function authWithLoginAndPassword() {
    const response = await fetch('');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i write the if statement with the mistake, for example if logins doesn't match, the div appears with an error that the login is incorrect and border turns red. and similarly with the password, but another div appears there

Comment: you can simply check value ```loggedUser``` if(loggedUser), it means username and password is correct. otherwise show error in username and password div.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the array filter function. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
async function getUsers() {
    const response = await fetch('');
    const users = await response.json();
    return users;
}  

submit.addEventListener('click', async ()=> {
    try {
        const users = await getUsers();
        const authenticatedUser = users.filter(user => {
          return user.login === loginUser && user.password === password;
        })[0]; // 0 index returns first found user with matching properties.

        if (authenticatedUser) {
         // authenticated 
        } else {
         // not authenticated
        }
    } catch(e) {

    }
});
```

Now the authenticatedUser is either a user object which matches login and password properties of the loginUser or undefined.

Comment: thank you, but how can i write the if statement with the mistake, for example if logins goesn't match, the div appears with an error that the login is incorrect and border turns red. and similarly with the password, but another div appears there

Comment: You could add an error class to the parent element which toggles the visibillity of an error message element. I made an example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/7vr91nze/12/